# How do I access base R on my windows and not R studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am having trouble installing packages in R studio. I want to see whether or not it is a problem with the IDE or with R itself so I would like to access base R and try installing the package there. However I can't figure out how to access base R without R studio. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to install anything. If you use RStudio for R programming, you have to have an R installation. And this installation will include `Rgui.exe`. Search for it in your program folder (or hard drive if R is installed elsewhere). (Btw. I don't think this will solve your issue.)

Comment: If you can use Rstudio, R is already installed. So you could even install new packages from command prompt with: `c:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe -e "install.packages('package_name', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')"`. Note that the path is going to be specific to your version and setup.

Comment: What OS are you using?